# Spring tags don't work in JSF xhtml files

Tags: jsf-2, spring-security

I am new to JSF and Spring. I am trying to use Spring Security with JSF. I have designed an XHTML page as below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/tags"
    xmlns:form="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form">
<head>
    <title>JSF Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <f:view>
    <p>This page should be authenticated!</p>
    <a href="<spring:url value="/j_spring_security_logout" htmlEscape="true" />">Logout</a>
    <div>Test: <spring:url value="/j_spring_security_logout" htmlEscape="true" /></div>
  </f:view>
</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to add a logout link using the `spring:url` tag. However, firstly this gives an error that `href` attribute cannot contain <. To troubleshoot this I removed the `a` tag and used the `div` to test whether I am able to get the desired value from the `spring:url` tag. I found that the `spring:url` tag is not being parsed and appears as it is in the source of the generated page.

Instead of using XHTML page if I use JSP page with taglibs instead of xmlns, everything works fine. I am not able to understand why it is not working with XHTML files.

My `Faces Servlet` is mapped to `.jsf` and `springSecurityFilterChain` is mapped to `/*` (without the space in between). I tried mapping `springSecurityFilterChain` to `*.jsf` and that too doesn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facelets is a XML based view technology. Nesting tags as an attribute of another tag is invalid XML. All `<spring:url>` effectively does is prepending the context path, you could also do it yourself:

```
<a href="#{request.contextPath}/j_spring_security_logout">Logout</a>
```

The HTML escaping is not relevant since you are not passing any parameters through it.

Comment: I tried it but it does not prepend the context path. As a workaround I removed the leading / (forward slash).

Comment: Oh boy, you're right. I'll update the answer. I was pretty certain that it did it.